# template< class Iterator > Is Iterator here predefined or any name can be used?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

Consider the code:

```
template< class Iterator>
Iterator calc( Iterator a , Iterator b ){   
   if( *a == 'c' && a != b ) ++a ;
   return a ;
}
```

Is `class Iterator` important or can we give it any name like `class T`?

```
template< class T>
T calc( T a , T b ){
   if( *a == 'c' && a != b ) ++a ;
   return a ;
}
```

Are both these examples the same?

Answer (score 2):

The two are exactly the same, yes. The name `Iterator` just makes it clearer to the reader of your code what sorts of arguments `calc` is expecting to be passed in, whereas `T` isn't particularly illuminating. Either way, the name of the template parameter is just a name - it has no other meaning.

---

The C++ concepts proposal (which you had originally tagged your question as, but isn't strictly relevant to the question) would allow you to write something that is actually more meaningful:

```
template <Input_iterator T>
T calc(T a, T b) { ... }
```

This would affect the overload resolution on `calc`, such that `calc(1, 2)` would now not even consider this function -- rather than throwing a compile error when you do `*a`.

But even here, the `T` is just a name, nothing more.